# XML Schema with repeating elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am trying to deserialise the following XML:

```
<queries>
    <query name='abc'>
        <statement>SELECT * FROM table1</statement>
        <label row='1' name='id'/>
        <label row='2' name='name'/>
    </query>
    <query name='another'>
        <statement>SELECT * FROM table2</statement>
        <label row='1' name='myTabID'/>
        <label row='2' name='myTabName'/>
    </query>
</queries>
```

To validate the schema I am using:

```
<xs:complexType name="Queries">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="query" type="Query"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Query">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="statement" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="label">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="row" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Validation is failing with the message:

> Not valid.
>   Error - Line 7, 48: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 48; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'label'. No child element is expected at this point.
>   Error - Line 9, 31: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 31; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'query'. No child element is expected at this point.

What am I missing please?  Do I need to specify a different tag than sequence?  I want to enforce at least one query existing.

Thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message complains about the definition

```
<xs:element name="label">
```

and the use

```
<label row='1' name='id'/>
<label row='2' name='name'/>
```

The [default values (W3)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`  is 1, so you can only use one label there. You need to change it if you like to use more labels. Use `unbounded` for arbitrary amount.

Also note that similar `maxOccurs` adjustment (`unbounded` or greater than `1`) is needed for `query` (as commented by [@kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes))

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found the information that the default values for min and max was 1... Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="queries">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="query" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="statement"/>
          <xs:element name="label" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="row" use="optional"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"    use="optional"/>
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Comment: OP can try a lot, but I guess he wants something that works. Maybe you explain where you made changes and how the changes are supposed to eliminate the problem.

Comment: you just beat me to the punch i think like you +1